# Sequelize , override specific columns values with mysql funcitons

Tags: sequelize.js

I need to use an specific function in the getter and setters of an specific value on a query, like this:

`SELECT AES_DECRYPT(COLUMN, UNHEX(SHA2('PASSWORD',512))) FROM TABLE;`

How can I approach this using sequelize?  This function is specific for MySQL

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I could find was declaring an array of the columns (attributes in Sequelize) setting the value of the column (attribute) with Sequelize.fn to execute the MySQL function.

```js
// model.js
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    // Other attributes
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.BLOB('medium'),
        get () {
            const val = this.getDataValue('email');
            return val ? val.toString('utf8') : null;
        },
        set (value) {
            this.setDataValue('email', Sequelize.fn('AES_ENCRYPT', value, 'MY_SUPER_SECRET_KEY'));
        },
        allowNull: false,
    },
    // Other attributes
    }, {
        // Other model options
    }
);

User.basicAttributes = [
    // Other attributes
    [Sequelize.fn('AES_DECRYPT', Sequelize.col(`user.email`),   'MY_SUPER_SECRET_KEY'), 'email'],
    // Other attributes
]
```

Later on, I use that array in the queries performed:

```js
// controller.js
const data = await User.findAll({
    attributes: User.basicAttributes,
});
```

You can use that working code and adapt it to your needs.

I couldn't find a way to call AES_DECRYPT in the getter. If someone knows how to do that (and avoid using the array of attributes), I'd be very interested in the answer.